# How does one get points in Angry Birds GO?

Tags: angry-birds-go

In *Angry Birds GO* I get points during the race, but not constantly. It isn't tied to ether distance passed, speed, position or blocks smashed.

How do you get points during the race in Angry Birds GO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Hitting opponents
- Jumping
- Collecting coins
- Using speed pads